# Why color styling doesn't work in this case?

Tags: html, css, less

I have the following html markup:

```
<div class="header-menu">
    <span class="header-title noselect">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        <a href="/" class="header-title-value">
            {{ headerVm.menu.current.title }}
        </a>            
    </span>
</div>
```

A this rules in `*.less` file:

```
.header-menu {
    .header-title {
        color: red;
        a {
            font-size: 2em;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
    }
}
```

which is translated into css:

```
.header-menu .header-title{
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#f00
}
.header-menu .header-title a {
    font-size:2em;
    font-family:'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-weight:300
}
```

In this case the `color` property of a `header-title` doesn't affect `a` tag, but if i place it inside `a` rules it works. Also i've tried to set `!improtant` on the `color` property which also didn't help. And another interesting moment if i've move font properties from `a` rules and put them into `.header-menu .header-title` this would work for the `a` tag, but not the `color` property.

In Chrome inspector i've seen that after my rules for `a` goes rules from bootstrap, but not from `header-title`. Actually i'm not that interested in how to fix this, but why it works in the way it works and proper fix/best practice advice as well =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default the `<a>` tag does not inherit the color from its parent elements. Try this instead to force the inherit:

```
.header-menu {
    .header-title {
        color: red;
        a {
            color: inherit;
            font-size: 2em;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is simpler and safer (better browser coverage) to just set the color on the `a` element, instead of using inheritance.

Comment: Yes, but he had noted already that that worked, so I figured he already knew it and didn't want to do it that way.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about this. Can you elaborate on jukka-k-korpela's comment, which way is better and why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the a tag the color property and value to see it's effect